# How to calculate average time interval based on unique value?

Tags: r, time, aggregate, intervals

I'm having trouble when trying to calculate the average time interval (how many days) between appearances of the same value in another column.

My data looks like this:

```
dt      subject_id
2016-09-13         77
2016-11-07       1791
2016-09-18       1332
2016-08-31         84
2016-08-23         89
2016-08-23         41
2016-09-15         41
2016-10-12         93
2016-10-05         93
2016-11-09         94
2016-10-25         94
2016-11-03         94
2016-10-09        375
2016-10-14         11
2016-09-27         11
2016-09-13         11
2016-08-23         11
2016-08-27         11
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
subject_id  mean_day
41          23
93          7
94          7.5
11          13
```

I tried to use:

```
 aggregate(dt~subject_id, data, mean)
```

But it can't calculate mean from Date values. Any ideas?

Comment: How is mean calculated? 23 and 7 doesn't look like mean. They are just differences between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would be something like this:

```
df$dt <- as.Date(df$dt)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
    summarise((max(dt) - min(dt))/(n()-1))
#        <int>                          <time>
#1          11                       13.0 days
#2          41                       23.0 days
#3          77                        NaN days
#4          84                        NaN days
#5          89                        NaN days
#6          93                        7.0 days
#7          94                        7.5 days
#8         375                        NaN days
#9        1332                        NaN days
#10       1791                        NaN days
```

I think it's a starting point for you ... you can modify as you want.

Comment: "I think it's a starting point for you". I think you're being humble; this looks like a great solution to me.